# Mac terminal not responding at all

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, homebrew, bin

[Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hiRH.png)

Hi, My terminal is gone. all I can see is :

```
"Last login: Tue May  5 08:29:01 on ttys007 [İşlem tamamlandı]".         
(it means "job completed")
```

I was downloading `sth` from homebrew and save sth to `root`.  I think i did `sth` wrong and terminal is not responding now, whatever I push. How can I fix it? Even apple doesn't know, I called them.

On the top, its written that  `Terminal -- java_home --bash 80X24" and "  Terminal -- bash --bash 80X24`

Its trying to command `sth`. Its blinking for like 2 minutes and then stops. It turns to just `Terminal 80X24`

Thank you very much..

[Terminal Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMaC8.png)

[Terminal Java Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlXEp.png)

Comment: Try launching a fresh new terminal window and see if that resolves your issue.  
Also, could you translate the text on the 2nd screenshot?

Comment: Did you try control+C to stop the interrupt terminal ?

Answer (score 1):

Just try hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It should take you back to how your terminal was.